# Django and Tastypie API key signal connect yields ImportError: cannot import name User

Tags: python, django, tastypie

In one of my `django 1.6` apps, `SOME_APP`, I attempt to hook up a `tastypie` signal so that I can have API keys generated on `User` creation, as in the `tastypie` docs:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html

in `MY_SITE/SOME_APP/signals.py` I have:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from tastypie.models import create_api_key

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)
```

and in `MY_SITE/SOME_APP/__init__.py` I have:

```
from . import signals
```

When I attempt to run my development server, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/USER/git/MY_SITE/SOME_APP/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import signals
  File "/home/USER/git/MY_SITE/SOME_APP/signals.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tastypie.models import create_api_key
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/models.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tastypie.compat import AUTH_USER_MODEL
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/compat.py", line 14, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 127, in get_user_model
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 271, in get_model
    self._populate()
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 63, in <module>
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 51, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 480, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 310, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 262, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/USER/git/MY_SITE/MY_SITE/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    from SOME_APP.api.resources import PostResource #for tastypie REST API access
  File "/home/USER/git/MY_SITE/SOME_APP/api/resources.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/virt-develop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/authentication.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tastypie.compat import User, username_field
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

**What is causing this error and how can I fix it?**

Thank you for any thoughts and suggestions :)

Comment: can you post your django verson `django.VERSION`?

Comment: @dhana - sure:
  `>>> django.VERSION
  (1, 6, 1, 'final', 0)`

Comment: If you're at all comfortable making your own changes to tastypie, [here's](https://github.com/mpyatishev/django-tastypie/commit/59515720c94b97802cbb32904db549845f30cdae) an example of how somebody else fixed the problem.

Comment: @Alex - Thanks for the info! I'm not completely comfortable making my own changes. Might have to wait and see if tastypie merges in a fix. I guess I will have to keep an eye on it.